# Which cache is kicking

Tags: theme-development, themes

I have been struggling with a site that I inherited from another developer.

My main problem is that, changes I make in the css file of the template don't get picked up right away, indicating that some kind of caching is kicking in. What I checked is.

1. The .htaccess file for any caching directive.
2. Any caching WordPress plugins that might be activated.
3. Any caching functionality implemented by the hoster.
4. Cloudflare or any other CDN.
5. [EDIT] I have tried different browsers and computers so the caching is server side.

As you can imagine none of the above is enabled and yet my changes to the css take some hours to be seen.

I am not a WordPress expert in any way, so I am asking the community of what other caching mechanism I might missing here.

Thanks

Comment: It's likely just your browser. Do you see the changes if you use a different browser, or use private browsing?

Comment: I should have pointed that out. I tried different browsers, computers and all. The caching is server side.

Comment: So what file are you editing exactly? Just style.css, or something else?

Comment: style.css located in my theme folder. I am sure that is the one used for styling through Developers Tools, therefore the changes I make there are visible after a while

Comment: You could change the file version each time the file gets updated. To do this, go to your functions.php file and find where the style-sheet is being enqueued (or registered) - it will look something like `wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );` and change it to `wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), filemtime( get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' ) );` . This will change the file version each time you save it, forcing the new version to get loaded.

Comment: @Bob You are my hero. The file wasn't properly added to the template as described [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/). It was hard coded in the header.php file. Added the wp_enqueue_style function in functions.php and now all works as it should. I suggest you write an answer to this.

Comment: @pierostz I've added my comment as an answer. In any case, really glad I could help :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the file version each time the file gets updated. To do this, go to your `functions.php` file and find where the style-sheet is being enqueued (or registered) - it will look something like:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
```

and change it to:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), filemtime( get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' ) );
```

This will change the file version each time you save it, forcing the new version to get loaded.

As you very correctly pointed out, the styles have to be properly added in `functions.php`, not hard-coded in `header.php` or elsewhere.